# Google Sheets Number of columns

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to read a sheet and i want to know it's dimensions (number of columns, number of rows).

What is the easiest way to obtain these? From

```
Get get = Sheets.getSheetsService().spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId, sheetRange);
```

I want to know the number of columns, that contain data, I don't want the actual size of the sheet, since there might be lots of empty cells.

Is this possible in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say you "*don't want the actual size of the sheet, since there might be lots of empty cells.*" Not sure if you mean you just want the max data range, `last row` and `last col` with data? or just the count of rows and columns with data

If last row/col data range, you can  use [spreadsheets.values.get()](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get) and find the `length` of the returned [values](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values#ValueRange) for rows and then the largest `array.length` in the list for the `last column` with data. 
This works because [returned values](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values#ValueRange) exclude extra empty rows and cols:

> For output, empty trailing rows and columns will not be included.

Example using google apps script & javascript that can be tested in google apps script 
[hoping you can get an idea of the process - haven't used Java in awhile and didnt want it to be a point of confusion]

```
function getDimensions () {
  var data = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get("SPREADSHEET_ID","SHEET_NAME"); 
  // returned value list[][]
  var arr = data.values;

  // last row with data
  var rows = arr.length;

  // last column with data
  var cols = arr.reduce(function(accumulator, el, i) {
    if (i == 1) { accumulator = accumulator.length } 
    return Math.max(accumulator, el.length);
  });
}
```

**edit:** An easy way to get the columns would be to add `majorDimension` parameter in `Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get("ID","SN", {majorDimension: "COLUMNS"})` then the `arr.length`  returns the column length

From there you could filter out the empty columns or rows that are between the ones which contain data - to get a count of only data rows/cols; as far as I am aware there is no way to get that count from the API itself.

Comment: That's exactly what I was going for, I was confused because the range also included all the empty cells.

Thanks!