# Google sheets api: how do I get row and column index?

Tags: php, google-sheets-api, google-api-php-client

Is there any way to get row and column index via google sheets API?

Here's how I get data by following official sample.

```
// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);

$spreadsheetId = '{MY_SPREADSHEET_ID}';
$range = 'dummy!A1:E';
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
$values = $response->getValues();
var_dump($values);
```

This gives me back data in array.

Additionally I want to get cell's index (ex. column A and row 4) which cell the data coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the API Reference for [values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get) you should have a range string available in the response. There is not a convenient row / cell index in this response, because this response is not guaranteed to be 1:1 with the requested range:

> #### Response body
>
> If successful, the response body contains an instance of ValueRange.
>
> #### ValueRange.range:
>
> The range the values cover, in A1 notation. For output, this range indicates the entire requested range, even though the values will exclude trailing rows and columns. When appending values, this field represents the range to search for a table, after which values will be appended.

So, because trailing empty cells are not returned, you are not guaranteed to get a 5x5 value array when requesting, for example, `A1:E5` but column E is empty

If you want to work with the row and column index, you can use the Spreadsheets.get method and specify the ranges you want to retrieve (with `includeGridData` flag set). This call will return a [Spreadsheet resource](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets). You'd then find the sheet you want to use (probably the first in sheets if you didn't request ranges from any other sheets), and inspect the various [`data`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#GridData) it holds.

Additionally, if you programmatically requested the given range (when using `Spreadsheet.values`) based on a row, column input, you can use that input, the length of the returned value array, and the length of the largest row to compute the working indices. Obtaining those maximum indices can be done as is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47231584/9337071).